# How to use own data with quantstrat and quantmod?

Tags: r, xts, quantmod, quantstrat

I am learning quantstrat and is working on a project where I use a local csv file which I exported from metatrader5. I managed to load the data into an xts object and called it `fulldata_xts` of which I have created subsets `bt_xts` and `wf_xts` for the backtest and walk forward respectively. Below is the head of `fulldata_xts`. I have added the other columns other than the standard OHLCV.

```
                        EURUSD.Open EURUSD.High EURUSD.Low
2010-01-03 16:00:00     1.43259     1.43336    1.43151
2010-01-03 17:00:00     1.43151     1.43153    1.42879
2010-01-03 18:00:00     1.42885     1.42885    1.42569
2010-01-03 19:00:00     1.42702     1.42989    1.42700
2010-01-03 20:00:00     1.42938     1.42968    1.42718
2010-01-03 21:00:00     1.42847     1.42985    1.42822
                    EURUSD.Close EURUSD.Volume EURUSD.Vol
2010-01-03 16:00:00      1.43153           969          0
2010-01-03 17:00:00      1.42886          2098          0
2010-01-03 18:00:00      1.42705          2082          0
2010-01-03 19:00:00      1.42939          1544          0
2010-01-03 20:00:00      1.42848          1131          0
2010-01-03 21:00:00      1.42897          1040          0
                    EURUSD.Spread EURUSD.Year EURUSD.Month
2010-01-03 16:00:00            12        2010            1
2010-01-03 17:00:00            15        2010            1
2010-01-03 18:00:00            15        2010            1
2010-01-03 19:00:00            14        2010            1
2010-01-03 20:00:00            15        2010            1
2010-01-03 21:00:00            14        2010            1
                    EURUSD.Day EURUSD.Weekday EURUSD.Hour
2010-01-03 16:00:00          4              2           0
2010-01-03 17:00:00          4              2           1
2010-01-03 18:00:00          4              2           2
2010-01-03 19:00:00          4              2           3
2010-01-03 20:00:00          4              2           4
2010-01-03 21:00:00          4              2           5
                    EURUSD.Session EURUSD.EMA14
2010-01-03 16:00:00              0           NA
2010-01-03 17:00:00              0           NA
2010-01-03 18:00:00              0           NA
2010-01-03 19:00:00              0           NA
2010-01-03 20:00:00              0           NA
2010-01-03 21:00:00              0           NA
                    EURUSD.EMA14_Out
2010-01-03 16:00:00                0
2010-01-03 17:00:00                0
2010-01-03 18:00:00                0
2010-01-03 19:00:00                0
2010-01-03 20:00:00                0
2010-01-03 21:00:00                0
```

I am trying to create my own indicator using the following code:

```
add.indicator(strategy1.st, name = sentiment,
     arguments = list(date = quote(Cl(mktdata))), 
     label = "sentiment")
```

I have based the above code from a course on datacamp but is similar to what is being discussed [here](https://quantstrattrader.com/2014/09/16/nuts-and-bolts-of-quantstrat-part-ii/). My questions are:

1. How can I specify my own data i.e. `bt_xts` on the code above. Please correct me if I am wrong but from what I gather, the mktdata object gets created when the data is downloaded using quantstrat facilities which is not applicable on my case since I read the data off of csv and converted it to data table then to an xts object.
2. The function `sentiment` on the inside the `add.indicator` code above for now only functions returns 0,1,2 (stay out, bullish, bearish) based on day of week. I plan to develop this further once I get the other part of the strategy working. This function takes in a variable date hence the `arguments = list(date = quote(Cl(mktdata)))` part is incorrect. What should I put inside the `quote()` to specify the date column of my data, `bt_xts`?